# How to Continues execution with hard assertion on testNG?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, listener

After hard assertion give exception on testNG it moves to onTestFailure listener for screenshot, but execution is not continuing. How to continue the execution?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, once Assertions fails then it will throw exception.

see for example https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

if need to continue after Assertion fails then need to handle that thrown exception, so need to use `try/catch`

But make a note that, when Assertions are handled by `try/catch` then test will be passed as exceptions are handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [QAF TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks). It provides [Verify and assert methods](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/javadoc/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/util/Validator.html).  You can use validator as Below:

```
Validator.verifyThat(actual,Matchers.equalTo(expected));
Validator.verifyTrue(condition, failMessage, successMsg);
Validator.verifyFalse(condition, failMessage, successMsg);
```

Further more for web and mobile test it has inbuilt wait, [verify and assert](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) methods available with element object.